# How to speed up raster/map algebra in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, map-algebra, postgis-raster

I am testing map algebra with PostGIS (2.1 with PostgreSQL 9.3) on two images, and found it to be rather slow. For example, dividing two images of 7200 * 3600 pixels took 110 ~ 120s on a desktop with i7 3.4 GHz CPU; the same operation with the same data took ArcGIS (10.1) 15 ~ 16s.

The SQL statement tested was based on [this PostGIS example](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_MapAlgebra_expr.html) as follows:

```
SELECT ST_MapAlgebra(t1.rast,t2.rast
        ,'([rast1]+0.001)/([rast2]+0.001)') AS rast
FROM img1 t1, img2 t2
```

The two rasters were imported using the following options:

```
 raster2pgsql -d -M -C -I -s 4326 ...
```

I did not use filesystem storage or tiling.

My question is:

What's the best way (if possible) to improve the above SQL for map algebra?

Answer (score 1):

How about testing [St_MapAlgebraExp](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebraExpr2.html)

`SELECT ST_MapAlgebraExp(t1.rast,t2.rast
        ,'([rast1]+0.001)/([rast2]+0.001)') AS rast
    FROM img1 t1, img2 t2`

Comment: The page you linked to says "ST_MapAlgebraExpr is deprecated as of 2.1.0. Use ST_MapAlgebra instead."

Comment: It's really crasy, I'm using it and it's taking 10 s for a large raster